# How to store value of attribute from firebase realtime database into a variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I have created a website, where I connected it to firebase using Js.
I want to access the array 'correct' outside of the scope of the function, i.e. I want to make it accessible globally.

[image]

```
var mcqq = firebase.database().ref("mcq_choice/");
mcqq.orderByChild("mcq_choice").on("value", function (data) {
  data.forEach(function (data) {
    correct_option = data.val().correct)
  });
});

console.log(correct_option)
```

The console.log(correct_option) is showing undefined error when being called outside the function.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `correct_option` is defined inside your function and that is why `console.log(correct_option)` works there, but it doesn't work outside. The variable is scope defined so it is not recognized outside the function.

You should define the variable outside the function by writing `let correct_option;` preferably before

```js
var mcqq = firebase.database().ref("mcq_choice/");
mcqq.orderByChild("mcq_choice").on("value", function (data) {
  data.forEach(function (data) {
    correct_option = data.val().correct;
    // console.log(correct_option)

  });
});
```

This way the variable can be accessed outside your function.

For more information about *scope* inside JavaScript you can check this : [scope in javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)

Comment: When I declare it before the function block and printing it in console, it just prints undefined.

I don't know where to return the value of the function or how exactly the function is called to catch value if i do use return

Comment: Try a few of the following and see how it works. 1. change the name of the parameter from `data` in one of the functions to something else. 2. you can also try to use `var correct_option = data.val().correct;` inside the function and get rid of the `let correct_option;` before var mcqq. 3. Try debugging inside your most nested function by using `console.log(data)` to see if it works as intended and then `console.log(data.val())` to see if it has the intended values.